# How to @joincolumn key from table a with foreign key in table b in JPA/Spring

Tags: spring, jpa, foreign-keys, joincolumn

how do I link via `@joincolumn` an already existing key from table A with a field in table B.

In detail I have a class server with its key serverId. It has a one-to-one relation to a class license linked by the serverId from the embedded Class LicenseKey. Now the problem is, that my serverId is already defined as a ID and I got the error:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Column 'serverId' is duplicated in mapping for entity 'com.example.jpa.model.Server' (use '@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)' when mapping multiple properties to the same column)

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "server")
public class Server {

@Id
private String serverId;

 @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="version", referencedColumnName="version")
    @JoinColumn(name="serverId", referencedColumnName="serverId")
    private License license;
    
    // getter and setter    
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "license")
public class License {

    @EmbeddedId
    private LicenseKey id;
  // ...
}



@Embeddable
public class LicenseKey implements Serializable  {
    String version;
    String serverId;
 // ...
}
```

After that I tried to use  `@JoinColumn(name="serverId", insertable=false, updateable=false, referencedColumnName="serverId")` but it does not work and I got more errors. Maybe it is easy and someone can help me here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might resolve your issue.

LicenseKey

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
public class LicenseKey implements Serializable {

   private Long l_server_id;

   //
}
```

License

```
    @Entity
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class License {
    
        @EmbeddedId
        private LicenseKey licenseKey;
    
        @OneToOne
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
        @MapsId("l_server_id")
        private Server server;
    
    }
```

Server

```
 @Entity
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class Server {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long serverId;
    
        private String serverName;
    
            @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "server",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private License license;
    
    }
```

This is going to create the table structure like this

```
Hibernate: create table license (l_server_id bigint not null, primary key (l_server_id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table server (server_id bigint not null auto_increment, server_name varchar(255), primary key (server_id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: alter table license add constraint FKkope30d18c3etsmqjipi6yrw9 foreign key (l_server_id) references server (server_id)
```

Comment: And how do I access the license via Server-Table in direct way?  If I apply my whish in Database without JPA it is pretty simple, but JPA seems to be rather obstructive. I am confused that it is that difficult.

Comment: I have edited the answer. you can use fetchType as Eager to directly fetch the License data whenever you will query the server table.

Comment: This is working for one Key @MapsId("l_server_id"). But MapsId is not repeatable for a second value version of the composite key. How could that work ?

Comment: MapsId is mapping the Id. For other parameters try to use @joincolumn

Comment: Then it is also working, if I do it right.  Would it be helpful if i write the complete code here ?

Comment: From which entity this version is coming? Add that detail as well.

Comment: From both of course

Comment: Can you give the details of this version field? where this is present n all

Comment: @Column(name = "VERSION")
    private String version;  // In Server and in License

Comment: In general, I think @primarykeyjoincolumn on server could also help to solve this issue.

Comment: I am not getting one point. If your version field is part of server entity they how you are going to keep two version values for same serverid?  If it is not possible then why are you trying to keep embedded id of serverId and versionId?

Comment: You are absolutely right, the model is not correct here.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the issue is in the error message itself.

> Column 'serverId' is duplicated

As the `Server` class has field `serverId`, the JPA has to map that field to a database column `serverId`.
Now the second field `license` is a separate field in `Server` class with two `@JoinColumn`s. This means it has to match to two other columns `version` and `serverId`(duplicated). This is not possible, right?

From your code, it is difficult to understand what is your database structure. Could you also provide that to suggest a solution.

From what I am assuming, you may either change to `@Id private String id` or change the `serverId` name in the `@JoinColumn`.

Comment: The ER-Model is: The Server with it's primary-Key "serverId" has an one-to-one relation to License. The License itself is a key-combination of "serverId and version", but this is not the problem. You may forget the version. For me it is about how to connect the given primary field "serverId" from Server with the field "serverId" from the class license! When I combine serverId and version then the key on the server will also be a composite one.

Comment: Do you mean the PK of "Server" table should also be a FK which points to "serverId"? For better clarification, you may add the details to your question. A screenshot of the two tables, the create/alter table commands related to these tables etc. This is needed to suggest the changes, because your current code won't work.

Comment: Exactly, the PK of Server "serverId" will be the foreign-key of table "license". This is the detail of the question how to join these both fields together.